# Why data in my table cannot be not updated?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I want to update data from my database using java. I have established my connection successfully and When I am updating the table,the data is not updated in the database.

My SQL is like this ::

```
UPDATE  tbl_Bus SET Bus_locX= 520.0,Bus_locY=220.0 WHERE Bus_ID=1
```

This statement does not update my table though it's working fine when I am using it directly in sql editor in MS Access.

My tbl_Bus

```
Bus_ID,Bus_LocX,Bus_LocY,Bus_RouteID
```

and the corresponding data are 1,1,1,1 even after running my app..

My codes

```
public boolean update_busLoc(double x,double y,int id)
{
    String query="UPDATE  tbl_Bus SET Bus_locX= "+ x +",Bus_locY="+y + " WHERE Bus_ID="+id;
    System .out.println(query);
    if (DB_connection!=null){
            try{
                     statement.execute(query);
                     return true;

                 }
            catch(SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Connection is not set up");
        return false;
    }

}
```

I use MS Access 2007
I am able to execute SELECT statements and it is working fine but with update I am having problems..
How do I sort this out?

Comment: To avoid SQL injection, don't concatenate SQL queries like that! Use SQL parameters instead: 

http://www.google.com/search?q=ado.net+sql+parameters

Comment: @Closure Cowboy: Right, in general. But in this case, the variables are type double and int. I cannot imagine a SQL-Injection in this case.

Comment: It couldn't happen with the code specifically the way it is, but on larger projects, I've seen variables change from numeric types to strings. `X` and `Y` aren't likely to do that, but you may as well use parameters everywhere.

Comment: do you have any errors ? we need more details :/

Comment: No errors , just it just returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
stmt.execute(query);
```

with

```
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: @Vimal Basdeo  , can you see any exception on your console ?

Comment: @Vimal Basdeo , try printing query on console and execute same on your DB using some IDE check what it does, try tracing out the problem

Answer (score 2):

Use executeUpdate instead of execute

Answer (score 2):

Is your connection set to autocommit? This might be the problem

Comment: Agree. It is the most possible cause:)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is help full

1. Replace execute with executeUpdate
2. use preparedStatement instead of statement

   PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE  tbl_Bus SET Bus_locX=?,Bus_locY=? WHERE Bus_ID=?");
        pstmt.setDouble(1, x);
        pstmt.setString(2, y);
        pstmt.setInt(3, id);

   ```
    if (DB_connection!=null){
            try{
                  pstmt.executeUpdate();
                     return true;


             }
        catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }


    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Connection is not set up");
        return false;
    }
   ```